# Unable to format SSD disk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Ok, I have a 64 GB SSD, and I tried to clean install the Linux on it.

But the problem is, the installation menu shows two disks: one 500 GB and another with available space of 32 GB. I tried advanced options with partitions, but nothing changed. So I installed the OS on 500 GB one, and tried to clean-safe erase the /dev/sdb using `blkdiscard`, `dd` and gparted etc. Nothing worked.

What am I supposed to do now?

```
nikolaos@nikolaos-LIFEBOOK-UH572:~$ sudo lsblk -f
[sudo] password for nikolaos: 
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                      
└─sdb1 ext4   Datas b87a6c63-41fa-49df-af7d-28944f026c34 
sda                                                      
├─sda2 ext4         beea8d91-433e-426e-9b16-38abcae7fb73 /
├─sda3 swap         974be45a-aec7-459e-b8b0-05d93b17acfa [SWAP]
└─sda1 vfat         1817-04A8                            /boot/efi
nikolaos@nikolaos-LIFEBOOK-UH572:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb     29,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1  29,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
sda    465,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2 457,4G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3   7,9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1   512M root  disk  brw-rw----

nikolaos@nikolaos-LIFEBOOK-UH572:~$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVT-1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   492GB  491GB   ext4
 3      492GB   500GB  8443MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA SanDisk SSD i100 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  32,0GB  32,0GB  primary  ext4

nikolaos@nikolaos-LIFEBOOK-UH572:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3991772       0   3991772   0% /dev
tmpfs             802928    9504    793424   2% /run
/dev/sda2      471956784 4826024 443133628   2% /
tmpfs            4014628   19360   3995268   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4014628       0   4014628   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         523248    3480    519768   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs             802928      76    802852   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Please start a terminal window and run the commands `df` ; `sudo lsblk -f` ; sudo lsblk -m` ;  `sudo parted -ls` and edit the result into your original question. Indent each line 4 spaces to render it as 'code'. This will help us help you.

Comment: Did you check if the connection between your computer and your ssd is secure? Usually if it is not connected well, the partition editor won't be able to show your SSD. Also, according what you have edited, you only have a 32 GB SSD. Are you sure that your SSD is 64 GB?

Comment: ok i will ty @sudodus

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy yes, i checked it on previous manual and was secure... yes i am sure thats why i want to burn it :( .

Answer (score 1):

### Summary concerning the size of the SSD

lsblk (size in GiB):

```
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb     29,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1  29,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

parted (size in GB):

```
Model: ATA SanDisk SSD i100 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32,0GB
```

Both of these tools see the SSD size as 32 GB, so I think that it is a 32 GB drive.

I found this link, that I think describes this drive and some other similar SSDs,

[SANDISK LAUNCHES TWO NEW SOLID STATE DRIVES (SSD) FOR TABLETS AND ULTRA-THIN NOTEBOOKS](https://www.sandisk.com/about/media-center/press-releases/2011/2011-05-31-sandisk-launches-two-new-solid-state-drives-(ssd)-for-tablets-and-ultra-thin-notebooks)

---

If the drive was sold to you as a 64 GB drive, I suggest that you tell the vendor to replace it with a a drive, that contains 64 GB, or that you can return it and get the money back.

Comment: FWIW, this is becoming a common scam from no-name Internet vendors -- because Flash RAM can have the controller rewritten to look like more capacity than it actually has, a 32 GB drive could look like 64 GB until it refuses to write beyond the 32 GB limit.  Partitioning from Ubuntu may have bypassed the controller hack.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

thank you again for you answers. Well the vendor is a friend of mine and when i ran on this pc hwinfo, when it had windows installed, i remember that the size was near 64. it's time i went to my vendor 'friend'.

Comment: Good luck :-) I wish that your friendship will survive this incident.